# CSS mobile navigation

Tags: html, css

I've encountered some difficulties while preparing mobile navigation. With the code below I am trying to achieve some basic dropdown list with menu items.

The problem is this navigation is based on hover property instead on click property. 
So when I click on menu using mobile device, I simultaneously click one of the menu items inside of it. (because there is no way to hover using fingers I believe :D )
Can I somehow simulate on click behavior using only CSS?
Or any simple way to change my code to work with js?

http://jsfiddle.net/hr6e69kp/

I have following HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="menuLinks">
        <li>
            <a href="#O-nas" id="aboutUsLink">O nas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#Aktualnosci" id="newsLink">Aktualności</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#Klienci-i-Partnerzy" id="clientsAndPartnersLink">Klienci i Partnerzy</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#Media" id="mediaLink">Media</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#Kontakt" id="contactLink">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 470px) {
   .menu {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 40px;
      z-index:10;
   }

   .menu ul {
      background:url("/Images/iconmonstr-menu-icon-128.png") no-repeat;
      width: 80px;
      height:40px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      left: -100px;
      color: white;
   }

    .menu li {
      display: none; /* hide all <li> items */
      margin: 0;
      color: #0096ff;
   }

   /*.menu li a, .menu li a:hover {
       color: #0096ff;
   }*/

   .menu .current {
      display: block; /* show only current <li> item */
   }

   .menu a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: left;
   }

   .menu .current a {
      background: none;
      color: white;
   }

   /* on nav hover */
   .menu ul:hover {
      background:url("/Images/iconmonstr-menu-icon-128.png") no-repeat;
      padding: 50px 50px 0 0;
   }

   .menu ul:hover li {
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      background-color:black;
   }

  .menu ul:hover .current {
     background: url(/Images/arrow.png) no-repeat 10px 7px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about using CSS, but with jQuery I believe you would just want to attach a click event to your menu div to show the child ul. You'd want to move display:none to the ul in the css rather than the li items doing it this way

```
 $(".menu").on("click", function(){
     $(this).children("ul").show();
 });
```

A basic example
http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/60sxq4pj/

Comment: Hmm. The idea is cool but it didn't work for me. I'll try some more tho :) Thanks

Comment: Apologies: next() doesnt work in this structure bc you want the  child of the div, I updated the answer with a basic fiddle